adding alternate date (e.g., julian) to Gnome panel
Is there an extension which would allow me to add an additional date (Julian) to the Gnome panel?

You could always use an extension such as this executor one which executes multiple shell commands periodically with separate intervals and display the output in gnome top bar, and make it run something like:
perl -MDateTime::Calendar::Julian -e '
  print DateTime::Calendar::Julian->
          now(time_zone => "local")->
          strftime("Julian: %A, %d %B 2024, %H:%M")'

Every minute.
